# In a Parallel.For, is it possible to synchronize each thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, thread-synchronization, parallel.for

In a `Parallel.For`, is it possible to synchronize each thread with a `WaitAll`?

```
  Parallel.For(0, maxIter, i =>
  {
       // Do stuffs

       // Synchronization : wait for all threads => ???

       // Do other stuffs
  });
```

Comment: Why not call Parallel.For twice?

Comment: Don't! Seriously. You're running on thread pool threads, *never* do any waiting or locking on a thread pool thread (it's a great way to get a deadlock, and if you're writing a library and someone uses it from e.g. ASP.NET, there's going to be a lot of fun) - most likely, there's a better way to do that. For example, why not call `Parallel.For` twice - first for the first part, when it ends, all the threads are done. Then the second part, another `For` call.

Comment: I agree with you but is it possible ?

Answer (score 5):

`Parallel.For`, in the background, batches the iterations of the loop into one or more `Tasks`, which can executed in parallel. Unless you take ownership of the partitioning, the number of tasks (and threads) is (and should!) be abstracted away from you. Control will only exit the `Parallel.For` loop once all the tasks have completed (i.e. no need for `WaitAll`).

The idea of course is that each loop iteration is independent and doesn't require synchronization with other concurrent work.

If synchronization is required in the tight loop, then you haven't isolated the Tasks sufficiently, or it means that [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) is in effect, and the problem can't be speeded up through parallelization.

However, for an aggregation type pattern, you may need to synchronize after completion of each Task - use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299(v=vs.110).aspx) with the `localInit` / `localFinally` to do this, e.g.:

```
// allTheStrings is shared so can't be mutated in a thread safe manner
var allTheStrings = new List<string>();
Parallel.For(         // for (
  0,                  // var i = 0;
  numberOfIterations, // i < numberOfIterations;
  () => new List<string> (), // localInit - Setup each task. List<string> --> localStrings
  (i, parallelLoopState, localStrings) =>
  {
     // The "tight" loop. If you need to synchronize here, there is no point in using Parallel.For
     // using parallel at all
     localStrings.Add(i.ToString());
     return localStrings;
  },
  (localStrings) => // local Finally for each task.
  {
     // Synchronization needed here is needed - run once per task
     lock(allTheStrings)
     {
        allTheStrings.AddRange(localStrings);
     }
  });
```

In the above example, you could also have just declared `allTheStrings` as

```
var allTheStrings = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
```

In which case, we wouldn't have required the `lock` in the `localFinally`.

Comment: The localFinally doesn't really help me because I want to start some computation in the same Parallel.For after synchronisation

Comment: In order to avoid synchronization, you'll need to ensure each `Task` gets its own instance of the resource(s) needed in the body (the tight loop). If you are synchronizing in the body, it is likely that your bottleneck is elsewhere and parallelizing will not improve performance. I've added comments?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't (for reasons stated by other users), but if you want to, you can use [`Barrier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This can be used to cause all threads to wait (block) at a certain point before X number of participants hit a barrier, causing the barrier to proceed and threads to unblock. The downside of this approach, as others have said, deadlocks

Answer (score 0):

You can lock and "serialize" the use of a resource.

[Parallel locks](https://dev.to/kamilbugnokrk/parallel-programming-in-c-53eg#locks)

```
var finalResult = 0;
var syncRoot = new object();

Parallel.For(0, maxIter, i => 
{
    var localResult = HeavyComputation(i.ToString());
    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        //one thread at the same time
        finalResult += localResult;
    }
});
```